# Could not resolve rosdep key 'rospkg'

Tags: ros, rosdep, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Similar to [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/58350/could-not-resolve-rosdep-key-message_generation/) but the solution there (replace `rosdep` files) does not change the result.

```
$ bloom-release --ros-distro groovy rqt_common_plugins groovy
: (cut)
#### Successfully generated 'quantal' debian for package 'rqt_bag_plugins' at version '0.2.15-0'
####

Placing debian template files into 'debian/groovy/rqt_logger_level' branch.

####
#### Generating 'oneiric' debian for package 'rqt_logger_level' at version '0.2.15-0'
####
Generating debian for oneiric...
Could not resolve rosdep key 'rospkg'
Resolve problem with rosdep and then continue to try again.
Continue [Y/n]? Y
Running 'rosdep update'...
Could not resolve rosdep key 'rospkg'
Resolve problem with rosdep and then continue to try again.
Continue [Y/n]? n
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/git-bloom-generate", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('bloom==0.3.3', 'console_scripts', 'git-bloom-generate')()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/bloom/commands/git/generate.py", line 247, in main
    run_generator(generator, args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/bloom/commands/git/generate.py", line 162, in run_generator
    gen.post_rebase, destination)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/bloom/commands/git/generate.py", line 101, in try_execute
    retcode = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/bloom/generators/debian/generator.py", line 231, in post_rebase
    self.generate_debian(data, stamp, distro)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/bloom/generators/debian/generator.py", line 371, in generate_debian
    self.resolved_dependencies = self.resolve_dependencies(self.depends + self.build_depends, debian_distro)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/bloom/generators/debian/generator.py", line 491, in resolve_dependencies
    resolved_depends[rosdep_key] = resolve_rosdep_key(rosdep_key, rosdep_view)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/bloom/generators/debian/generator.py", line 485, in resolve_rosdep_key
    return resolve_rosdep_key(rosdep_key, new_view)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/bloom/generators/debian/generator.py", line 485, in resolve_rosdep_key
    return resolve_rosdep_key(rosdep_key, new_view)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/bloom/generators/debian/generator.py", line 487, in resolve_rosdep_key
    .format(rosdep_key))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/bloom/generators/common.py", line 120, in exit
    raise GeneratorError(retcode)
GeneratorError: Error running generator

<== Error running command 'git-bloom-generate -y rosdebian --prefix release/groovy groovy -i 0'
Release failed, exiting.
```

The version of source used is [available here](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/commit/3f91f581712984f427fd99778db86802019aee8e).

What is wrong? Also, is there anything I should do when re-running `bloom-release` (since it failed this time. Looks like nothing is pushed yet to the release repository)? Thank you!

`python-bloom` 0.3.3-1, `python-rospkg` 1.0.20-1 on Ubuntu Quantal.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60271/could-not-resolve-rosdep-key-%27rospkg%27/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-04-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-04-09**:
What does `rosdep resolve rospkg` output?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-04-09**:
`ERROR: no rosdep rule for 'rospkg'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `rosdep` key for `rospkg` is `python-rospkg` not `rospkg`.

Your package must use `python-rospkg` not `rospkg` when declaring a dependency.

```
% rosdep --rosdistro groovy resolve python-rospkg
#pip
rospkg
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-04-09**:
Thanks! Turned out one of the pkgs in the metapkg has `rospkg` as `run_depend` ([suspicious commit](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/commit/2a0c544c761713cb178172fb3974d772aff65cae)). Hard to tell...

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-04-09**:
So is there a way to detect this `rosdep` error to happen in the end of releasing action? I think the best practice is to `rosdep resolve` for all dependencies in `package.xm`?